# How to change thousands separator to apostrophe in format string

Tags: python

The following prints a decimal number with commas as thousands separator:

```
num = 123456789
print(f"{num:,}")

123,456,789
```

According to [PEP-378](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0378/#alternative-proposal-from-eric-smith-originally-called-proposal-ii) (which seems relevant here?), the separator can be a comma, dot, space, apostrophe or underscore. I managed to get an underscore:

```
print(f"{num:_}")

123_456_789
```

But how do I get a dot, space, or most importantly to me, an apostrophe?

Comment: "As with locales which do not use a period as the decimal point, locales which use a different convention for digit separation will need to use the locale module to obtain appropriate formatting."

Comment: the [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) also only specifies "," and "_"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "proper" way to do this is using the `locale` module:

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'de_CH.utf8')
>>> locale.format_string('%d', 123457890, grouping=True)
"123'457'890"
```

In this case this requires the swiss-german locale to be installed on your system, but it is compatible with all installed locales, such that you can easily generate pretty much all formats that are used somewhere.

Comment: Oh, this is a bit annoying, having to use locale.format_string instead of f"...". But thanks, doing it the proper way is always good.

Comment: You can also use `'{:n}'` which is like `'{:d}'` but locale respecting, but as far as I know you can't use this with floating point numbers. May not be a problem in your case though.

Comment: I tried above code and I could swear it worked last week, now it doesn't. If I use it exactly as above, I get an 'unsupported locale error', if I adjust to use de_CH.UTF-8 which exists on my system, I get no apostrophes at all.

Answer (score 2):

the easy way to do this will be to store your string in a variable like `string`
and assuming you want apostrophes instead of underscores use,

```
print(string.replace('_',"'"))
```

Comment: you could directly `print(f"{num:_}".replace("_", "'"))`, no need for an intermediate variable.

Comment: I just assumed he would use it further,haha